# using newtons method to find abs max

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Use Newton's method to find the absolute maximum value of the function 
f(x) = 8x sin x,

0 ≤ x ≤ π
 correct to six decimal places

I know how to use Newton's method but this question is really annoying me how am I supposed to find the abs max with this info?

Answer (score 3):

The function is continuous on a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The absolute maximum will be one of the critical points or the end points.  To find the critical point, you must set the first derivative to zero.